# Python os.open() can not set umask to 777 (755 max)

Tags: python, file, umask

My python script creates a file if it doesn't exist, reads and writes that file. The script may be run by root (automated) or by the user (refresh request). I need the file to be created with write permission so that in both cases the file can be re-written.

```
import os
f = os.open('file', os.O_CREAT, 0777)
os.close(f)
```

but then...

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  0 Feb 22 13:51 file
```

**However, this script works and I don't understand the difference:**

```
import os  
f = os.open('file', os.O_CREAT)
os.fchmod(f, 0777)
os.close(f)
```

...and then:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  0 Feb 22 13:54 file
```

Comment: Note that `0777` is actually the default `mode`.

Comment: same result `sudo python test.py` with and `pyhton test.py`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, even without third argument, I still get `rwxr-xr-x` (755)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting `umask`, you're setting the file mode bits, which are *masked* by the `umask`.  [Per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open):

> Open the file file and set various flags according to flags and
>   possibly its mode according to mode. The default mode is 0777 (octal),
>   **and the current umask value is first masked out**. ...

Your `umask` value appears to be `0022`, thus masking out group and other user write permissions.

This

```
os.fchmod(f, 0777)
```

explicitly sets the file permissions to `0777` despite the `umask` value.

Comment: ahhhhh ok thanks, so in the one-liner what should the third argument be if I always want to create a file with 777?

Comment: @pinhead - Either that or explicitly set `umask` to zero.  Note that setting `umask` will impact everything you do in your process.  That's not a big deal if you're running single-threaded because you can set `umask` back, but in a multithreaded application it can be.

Comment: @pinhead, there's no way to do that as a one-liner unless you're running in an environment with umask 000 (which is dangerous)